# Silverlight TextBlock (wrapped) text not always rendering

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, textblock

My application uses multiple (approximately 128) TextBlocks for its UI - think a board of sticky notes. The Text of this TextBlock gets bound to the underlying model. For the majority of the TextBlocks this works fine, however every now and then the text is simply not showing on screen.

I've not found a consistent pattern when the text shows and when not, it seems completely random. I've verified the bindings and the data seems fine, the text has indeed the value of the data bound it. When the data context is changed, the text value changes, but it will still not render on screen. All the other properties of the TextBlock seem to work out as well (eg it's visible, it has a valid actual width and height, the opacity = 1 and so on ).

This happens only to several TextBlock objects in the collection, most of them render just fine.

Is there a limit to the amount of text that can be rendered ? Are there any other important properties that I can check ?

Edit: I've noticed this applies only to textblocks that have TextWrapping set to wrap. The issue doesn't seem to appear in elements that do not wrap their text.

Thanks,

xaml for reference (removed column / row definitions):

```
 <Grid 
      Background="{Binding Path=Background}"
      Canvas.ZIndex="1"
      Margin="10"
      >

     <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Title}">

        <TextBlock x:Name="_title"  
               FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="8"
               Foreground="{Binding Path=FontColor}" 
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Text="{Binding Path=Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Right" />

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: try giving the TextBlock a set width.

Comment: try to find out rendered xaml using "silverlight spy"

Comment: Do you have a fixed Height or something set on them somewhere be it directly or inherited that perhaps when the wrapped text is rendered it's there, but it's just not displaying because its viewable area is restricted? I'd ask to see your xaml.

Comment: What kind of element is the parent container of your 128 text boxes? Are they in a virtualized panel?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh  Thanks for the suggestion, I had already tried something similar and I couldn't see anything that stood out between a working and non-working element.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'll add the xaml to the original

Comment: @RobJacobs The parent is a Panel. I'm not sure what you mean by virtualized panel though ?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot. Thanks ! Interestingly giving the textblock a set width did fix it (for as far as I could see). Do you happen to know why this bug occurs on (seemingly random) instances and how giving it a set width fixes it ?

Comment: It shouldn't be random. It is based on how much space the TextBlock is given. If the TextBlock is contained within a control that spans forever, the TextBlock will span as well. So if you have a TextBlock contained within a ScrollViewer (note: Any ItemsControl has a ScrollViewer), the TextBlock will continue to grow horizontally. Give the parent control, or the TextBlock itself a set Width, and you'll be fine. Should I add this as an answer?